# Vuex dispatch doesn't return

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise, vuex

I have this code:

```
signin(context, payload, resolve) {
    console.log("SIGNIN action")

    const aemail = payload.locmail
    const apassw = payload.locpass

    backend.get("api/auth/signin", {
      headers: {
        'planck': 'FRESH'
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      params: {
        password: apassw,
        email: aemail
      }
    }).then(function(ret) {
      console.log("SENT")
      if (ret.data.auth === 'TRUE') {
        context.commit('authenticate', ret.data.planck)
        state.isAuthenticated = true
      } else {
        state.isAuthenticated = false
      }
      console.log(ret)
      return Promise.resolve(ret)
    });
  }
```

and when I call it from component:

```
this.$store.dispatch('signin', {
        locmail,
        locpass
      }).then(ret => {
        console.log(ret);
      });
```

then console log prints `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here? In documentation I read that I should use `resolve()` but then I get error that it's not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the `backend` promise in the `signin` action.

```
  signin(context, payload) {
    // ...

    // The action needs to return a Promise
    return backend.get("api/auth/signin", {
      /* ...*/
    }).then(function(ret) {
      /* ... */
    });
  }
```

---

Also, it looks like you're changing a `state` object in the action and this should be limited to mutations.

If you're using the [**strict** mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/strict.html) in development, you'll see a warning about this.

Comment: Thanks! I had to additionally put `return Promise.resolve(ret)` at the end.

Comment: You're returning from the `.then` function of the promise, not from the mutation function itself.

Comment: @kichik Not sure I get what you mean? I'm assuming that `backend` is an API call, like axios.

Comment: Yes, backend is an API call using axios. Used reference here because of `axios.create(args)`. And yes, `return Promise.resolve(ret)` must be used in `.then` function of the promise.

Comment: @EmileBergeron do you mean I should use commits for those changes?

Comment: @jeand'arme I can't know if `state` is really your Vuex store state, but if it is, yes, it should be changed using a commit.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the promise. Change your `signin()` function to this as @Emile Bergeron suggested:

```
signin(context, payload) {
    console.log("SIGNIN action")

    const aemail = payload.locmail
    const apassw = payload.locpass

    return backend.get("api/auth/signin", {
      headers: {
        'planck': 'FRESH'
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      params: {
        password: apassw,
        email: aemail
      }
    }).then(function(ret) {
      console.log("SENT")
      if (ret.data.auth === 'TRUE') {
        context.commit('authenticate', ret.data.planck)
        state.isAuthenticated = true
      } else {
        state.isAuthenticated = false
      }
      console.log(ret)
      return Promise.resolve(ret)
    });
  }
```